# How can i output a Java NODE in dom parser when i have used XPathConstants.BOOLEAN before?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xpath

I use Java and i have implemented a DOM parser in order to parse
an xml file.

I use XPath in order to navigate through elements/attributes in my xml document.

I have a specific xpath expression:

```
XPathExpression exprBoolean = xpath.compile("/root/customer/name/text()='George'");
Boolean test = (Boolean) exprBoolean.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
```

The previous expression returns true when customer George is in the xml file and false
when that name(George) is not in the xml file.

In my Java programming file, i have used the XPathConstants.BOOLEAN data type that maps to Java Boolean.

In case i find the George customer (if test == true) in the xml file,
i would like to output that node's children or the NODE itself.
Can i do that? 
I would like to return that specific NODE in case the boolean expression is true.
Is that possible?

My goal is to return a specific NODE in case that node contains that specific text().
But in order to test that, i shall do "text()='George'" and that expression
returns a boolean and NOT a Node.
So,how can i return a NODE after i jave used XPathConstants.BOOLEAN?

The **ParseFileXML class** is below:

```
package dom_parser;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class ParseFileXML {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {


  DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
  DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = builder.parse("root.xml");

  XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();   
  //XPathExpression exprBoolean = xpath.compile("/root/customer/name/text()='George'");

  /* new edit */
  XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/root/customer[name = 'George']");
  /* new edit */

  /*Boolean test = (Boolean) exprBoolean.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN); */

  /* new edit */
  NodeList customers = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
  /* new edit */


  for (int i = 0; i < customers.getLength(); i++) {

        //Output Names
        System.out.println("Name of Customer : " + customers.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
        //GET null!!! in here!!!

        XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("../../address/text()");
        Object result1 = expr1.evaluate(customers.item(i),XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList address = (NodeList) result1;

        for(int z = 0; z < address.getLength(); z++) {
            System.out.println("---- Address ---" + address.item(z).getNodeValue());
        }
  }


    }
}
```

**The root.xml file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <customer>
        <name>George</name>
        <address>NY</address>
        <telephones>
            <telephone>
                <number>1</number>
                <number>2</number>
            </telephone>
        </telephones>
    </customer>     

    <customer>
        <name>George2</name>
        <address>NY2</address>
        <telephones>
            <telephone>
                <number>12</number>
                <number>22</number>
            </telephone>
        </telephones>
    </customer>     
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should write an XPath expression selecting the node(s) you are interested in, as for example `/root/customer[name = 'George']`, then you can select them and further process them. Depending on the API you use the path would return an empty NodeList if no such nodes exists.

Here is an example:

```
  NodeList customers = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 


  for (int i = 0; i < customers.getLength(); i++) {


        XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("address");
        Node address = (Node)expr1.evaluate(customers.item(i),XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(address.getTextContent());


  }
```

Comment: In order to find the nodes that i'm interested in, i have used a boolean expression like the one you have already posted (/root/customer[name = 'George']). My problem is that i don't know how to process the specific NODES, cause i need a pointer that is going to point to the desirable NODES (a Java NODE value and not a boolean value). So i either get a true or a false value and not a NodeList.

Comment: The expression I posted is quite different from your expression. Your expression returns a boolean value, mine returns a node or node-set (but filtered by a predicate expression), exposed in the JAXP API as a DOM `Node` or `NodeList`. So use an expression with a predicate in square brackets and you will get node(s) meeting the condition in the predicate. Instead of `Boolean test = (Boolean) exprBoolean.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);` use `NodeList customers = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);`.

Comment: Or use `Node customer = (Node)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE); if (customer != null) { ... }`.

Comment: i edited the original code in my first post,i placed your code NodeList customers = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); but now i  get null for the NodeValue of the specific Node and i can't get the addresses with the relative path in expression expr1 and i don't know why, may you please help me on that? thanks

Comment: In the W3C DOM API, the node value of elements nodes is defined to be null so there is nothing wrong with that result.

Comment: ok with the null value then.As i saw the relative path for outputting the address of the specific customer "../../address/text()" returns a list of 0 elements [address.getLength() equals zero].But I don't think that the relative path is wrong,What is your opinion? thanks

Comment: I found my mistake, the right relative path in order to get the address is:"address/text()" and NOT "../../address/text()"

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use a relative path `address` to select the element node, and not `address/text()` to select a `text` node. Unless you need to work with mixed contents there is hardly any advantage to select a text node, selecting the element node suffices and you can always access its string value, both with XPath (`evaluate(foo, 'string()')`) or the DOM (`foo.getTextContent()`).